# Focus Indicator is Covered Up by Navigation Bar

Tags: reactjs, accessibility

I am working on a page where there are two rows in the header.

The first row has a "My Account" icon, Company Logo, and Logout.

The second row has a navigation bar.

When the Focus Ring/Focus Indicator highlights an item on the first row, the bottom of the focus ring is cut off by the navigation bar in the second row.

I am not allowed to change the spacing of the elements on the DOM.

***Is there a way I can change the layering so that all of the elements on the page are not changed in size or location, but the Focus Ring is not cut off by the navigation bar?***

The site built with React.

I've tried googling a number of things, but haven't turned up much specific to this issue.

I'm a little new to programming (my first job, first year).  I'm not totally sure where to even start.

Comment: No code - no guessing how to solve hypotetic code.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `z-index`. The second element is positioned in front of the first element and so it covers the focus indicator.

This allows you to specify how far 'forward' elements are on the page.

Assuming nothing is using `fixed` or `absolute` position within the `<div>`s you are working on this should solve your issue.

i.e.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="behind" z-index="1"></div>
    <div id="infront" z-index="0"></div> <!--The z-index is not really needed here so try without it first, it is to illustrate that the item in front at the moment should have a lower z-index than the one at the back-->
</div>
```

You may need to play with the `z-index` in order to get this to work (you can go to 999999 without a problem, but try and use as low a number as possible).

You may also have to fiddle with heights of elements if the site is poorly designed but without a code example I can only offer general advice and gotcha's

Answer (score 0):

Without a code example it is difficult to suggest a solution, but it sounds like your two rows are overlapping, and thereby hiding part of the focus indicator.

Three different solutions come to mind,

1. Change the height and placement of the two rows to avoid the overlap in the first place
2. Try using the CSS z-index property to control which element is rendered foremost
3. Using the CSS outline-offset property, with a negative value, i.e. -5px, to shrink the focus indicator and hopefully making it visible

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm actually hunting down what to do within the code, so I'm not even sure what kind of code sample to post.  Sounds like the z-index property is going to be the correct path to take since I can't actually change any of the dom elements and shrinking the focus ring is also not an option. 

Thanks for the response!